# My folder icon changed to archive icon in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I has add a project to another project by `git remote add` and `git subtree add` as subtree. After changes commited and push, i was found something in my gitlab page, folder icon of subtree was changed to archive icon, and if i click it cannot open the folder. I need to post screenshoot here, but i have not enought reputation to post image.

I try add another project with same way, another project is fine after add.

I expect it working like normal folder after add as subtree of project. Do anyone know why it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the project repo wasn't already cloned in your repo (as a nested Git repo) before your subtree command: adding a nested repo would result in a "archive" folder that you cannot open (representing actually a gitlink).

From "[Git subtree: the alternative to Git submodule](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree)", a command like:

```
git subtree add --prefix .vim/bundle/fireplace https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace.git master --squash
```

should work, provided the subtree folder fireplace did not already exists.

The [OP Alex San](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7918911/alex-san) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179595/my-folder-icon-changed-to-archive-icon-in-gitlab/56179793?noredirect=1#comment98988114_56179793):

> It was the issue: I cloned it first before the `subtree` command.

---

Another cause: the remote URL for the subtree repo is somehow not accessible from GitLab.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. It was the issue, i clone it first before subtree command. Again, many thanks :)